# Django redirect to detail page after authentication

Tags: python, django

here is my code

```
class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'main/userprofile.html'
    context_object_name = 'userprofile'
    model = ProfilePersonal
    
    # def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #     if request.user.is_authenticated:
    #         pass
    #     else:
    #         return redirect('/accounts/login/?next=userprofile/6')
            
    #     return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        comments_connected = Review.objects.filter(profile=self.get_object()).order_by('-date_created')
        context["comments"] = comments_connected
        context['comment_form'] = ReviewForm 
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            new_comment = Review(content=request.POST.get('content'),
                                  rating=request.POST.get('rate'),
                                  profile=self.get_object(),
                                    user = self.request.user)
        else:
            return redirect(f'/accounts/login  next=userprofile/{self.get_object()}')
        
        new_comment.save()
        return self.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Everything works fine except for the fact that if a user try to drop a comment and the user is not login in he will be be redirected to the login page but after authentication i want to redirect the user the user detail page where he was redirected from.
***for example if i was redirected from 127.0.0.1:8000/userprofile/6 after logging in i should be redirected to 127.0.0.1:8000/userprofile/6 in order to continue with what i was doing***

Answer (score 0):

I've solve it with

```
return redirect(f'/accounts/login  next=userprofile/{self.get_object().id}')
```